# Dynamic Android Layout Scaling (How-To?)

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android, xamarin

I'm stuck and I think wisdom (aka experience) is the only solution.

I need to be able to have boxes on a screen with data inside each box.  The number of boxes on the screen needs to be able to change and the boxes need to scale accordingly (as well as the text data inside of them) to allow for the additional boxes.

Example: I might start with only 8 boxes which are evenly spaced and displaying data at a reasonable font scale.

[image: Eight boxes per a screen]

As I add more boxes I need the rest of the boxes to scale down and allow everything on one screen.

[image: Sixteen boxes per a screen]

I am currently attempting to use a TableLayout, but I'm not certain how to make everything scale correctly.  Also, I'm generating everything programmatically by extending the TableLayout.  Can someone point me in the right direction.  Is there a better layout method that I'm not seeing? I'm sure I'm not the first person to need this, so are there examples available that I'm just not finding by searching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eventual solution was to build my own scaling function which took screen pixel dimensions and calculated the appropriate margin offsets to use on a relative layout.  It requires a complete redraw each time the scaling factor changes, which is annoyingly resource intensive.